# как убрать гланицы на изображении используя matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть изображение которое я перевожу в чб используя cv2.
потом мне необходимо сохранить измененное изображение на диск, для этого я использую matplotlib.pyplot.
всё оукей, но изображение сохраняется с белыми рамками по периметру.

[image: вот пример кода который редактирует моё изображение]

[image: вот изображение полученное на выходе, надо убрать эти белые рамки]

Comment: Приводите код виде текста, а не скриншота

Comment: а зачем вы используете matplotlib вообще?

Comment: Используйте метод imwrite из opencv. Так как plt.savefig сохраняет фигуру вместе с выведенной картинкой, а не только картинку.

Comment: @strawdog я его использовал для перевода фото в негатив
вот этой строчкой :
plt.imshow(img, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
но после этого автоматически появлялись рамки с разметкой:(

Comment: @Avernial Отлично!
спасибо!

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров буду знать

Answer (score 0):

Короче проблема заключается в том, что я использовал matplotlib. А он тут совсем не нужен.

Matplotlib я использовал для перевода фото в негатив, вот этой строчкой `plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)`. И казалось бы, ну вот, фото в негативе!
Но тут у нас появляются рамки и шкалы измерения(от шкал я избавился), а от рамок нет :(

Для избежания этой дрочки надо использовать cv2 и для перевода фото в негатив вам надо от 225 отнять ваше изображение(код висит ниже).

```
#метод переводит в негатив переданное изображение
def load_img(imgpath):
    img = cv2.imread(imgpath, 0) #загружаем фото
    negative_img = 225 - img #переводим в негатив
    cv2.imwrite("negative image.bmp", negative_img) #сохраняем
```